# Finding a basis for the vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I want to find a basis for the vector space, polynomials $p$ of degree $\leq 4$ which satisfy $p(2)=0$ and $p^{''}(3)=0$.

The basis which I found is $\{(x-3)^4-1, (x-3)^3+1, (x-3)+1 \}$. But in the rest of my exercise, I should find an orthonormal basis for my basis with respect to the following inner product:

$$\langle p(x),q(x) \rangle = \int_{1}^{3}p(x)q(x)dx,$$

which leads to a $\textit{very}$ big calculations.

**My Question**: Is there a better basis with respect to the defined inner product?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.

Thus, $$16+8a+4b+2c+d=0$$ and
$$6\cdot9+3a\cdot3+b=0,$$ which gives $$b=-54-9a,$$
$$d=200+24a-2c$$ and $$p(x)=x^4-54x^2+200+a(x^3-9x^2+24)+c(x-2).$$

Comment: Thank you all..

Comment: @A. Mpi You are welcome!